# Inserting into DB with Doctrine and Symfony - foreign key doesn't insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony with Doctrine and I try to insert data into DB. In my table `messages` there's one column `user_id` which is set as foreign key to `users.id`.
In my `Message` entitity there's this setter for `user_id`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Messages")
 */
class Message {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * */
    protected $user;

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setUserId($user_id) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function getUser_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

However it doesn't insert variable passed to my setter but `NULL`. Every other colums are filled with correct data while INSERTing just this one is not. I suppose it has something to do with the foreign key (there are proper data present in table `users`).

Part of controller code:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                if ($isLogged) {
                    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
                    $message->setUserId($user->getId());
                }
                $em->persist($message);
                $em->flush();
```

When I change the setter to this it's inserted properly :

```
    public function setUserId($user_id) {
         $this->random_column_which_is_not_foreignkey = $user_id;
    }
```

What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please update with the parts of the code that persist the entities

Comment: I have added some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [JoinColumn](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn).

Try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Messages")
 */
class Message {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        if ($isLogged) {
            $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $message->setUser($user);
        }
        $em->persist($message);
        $em->flush();
        // ...
```